# What does the `set -- $args` line do here, and why does it behave differently between Zsh and Bash?

Tags: bash, zsh, array, arguments

In the manpage for the version of `getopt` that comes with Mac OSX, an example is given that uses the construction `args=$(getopt optstring $*); set -- $args`. What does `set -- $args` do here?

Furthermore, consider the function and test string

```
f () {
    args=$(getopt o: $*)
    set -- $args
    for i; do
        echo $i
    done
}

f -o 123 xyz
```

In Bash 3.2 and 4.3, this produces

```
-o
123
--
xyz
```

but in Zsh 5.1, it produces

```
 -o 123 -- xyz
```

What causes the discrepancy? Is it because of Zsh's different word-splitting behavior, or something else? I tried different combinations of quoting and parameter expansion flags and couldn't really figure out what was going on under the hood in either shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bad code. `getopt` is pretty much unusable¹. Use the `getopts` shell builtin instead (it has two advantages: it can work, and it's available on all POSIX platforms).

What `args=$(getopt optstring $*); set -- $args` does is:

- Split each command line argument at whitespace and replace it by the list of whitespace-delimited words.
- Take each of the resulting word and interpret it as a wildcard pattern. If the pattern matches at least one file, replace the pattern by the list of matching files.
- Pass the resulting list of words to the `getopt` command.
- Store the output of the `getopt` command in the variable `args`. This is a string consisting of the command line arguments joined together with whitespace as the separator, and reordered to have options and their arguments, then `--`, then non-option operands.
- Split this string at whitespace, interpret each word as a wildcard pattern, and replace the pattern by the list of matching files if there are any.
- Use the resulting list as the positional arguments.

In Bourne/POSIX-style shells, `$foo` is the “split+glob” operator. [You need double quotes to get the value of a variable: `"$foo"`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters). But in zsh, `$foo` works differently: it expands to the value of `foo` except when `foo` is empty. So in zsh you get a single positional parameter.

The first use of the split+glob operator could be avoided by writing `getopt optstring "$@"`: this would pass the positional parameters exactly to `getopt`. But when parsing the output of `getopt`, splitting is unavoidable (you could disable globbing though), because `getopt` uses spaces to separate arguments. The problem with `getopt` is that the output is ambiguous: there's no way to distinguish a space that was in an argument from a space that `getopt` added as a separator.

The right way to do this is with `getopts`. It's robust and portable.

```
while getopts optstring OPTLET; do
  # We got the option -$OPTLET
  case $OPTLET in
    …
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))
# Now the positional parameters are just the non-option operands
```

¹  <sub>At least the BSD version. The GNU version adds features that make it usable.</sub>

Comment: I never realized the shell would perform globbing on the result of unquoted parameter expansions. Just one tangential question about your `getopts` example: does it matter if I call `shift` in every case statement versus calling `shift` all at once at the end?

Comment: @ssdecontrol If you call `shift` inside the loop, `getopts` will get out of synch. You'd also have to update `OPTIND`, which is how `getopts` keeps track of where it's at.

Answer (score 1):

`set -- $args` set the positional arguments base on content of `$args`. Now you will get the different behavior between `zsh` and other POSIX shells.

Because `zsh` does not perform [Field Splitting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05) by default, you will get one string, which is content of`$args`. You must to call splitting explicitly to get the same behavior as `bash` (and also other POSIX shells):

```
set -- ${=args}
```

`bash` perform `Field Splitting` on content of `$args`, produce four string as you got. You can check `$#` to know number of positional arguments after `set -- $args`.

Note that in case of `bash`, you should add `set -f` to turn off globbing as well.